# SwiftUI on app load - redirect to web URL

Tags: ios, swiftui

In my iOS app, I have a requirement to load a web URL on app load or app icon is tapped by the user.

application landing page has a UI but it will only appear after user press back button from the browser.

How to redirect to any URL as soon as app is open? I am using swift UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onAppear` should work well here:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainApp()
            .onAppear {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")!)
            }
    }
}

struct MainApp: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Philp Dukhov - Thanks. But I see an error if I copy past the code as is - Type 'WebView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'

Comment: @Manojkumar add `import WebKit`

Comment: @philp Dukhov - Thanks the code is working now. But the URL should be opened in a browser. How to change it?

Comment: @philp Dukhov Thanks for the answer. in simple terms I just need to open the URL in browser. In SafariView it appears like a pop up and display. How can this be just opened in browser. ------ as soon as app is loaded, it she redirect to a browser. Thats it.

Comment: even if I use the below code, it is not redirecting to the browser.
    var body: some View {
        if safariViewPresented {
            //Rectangle().foregroundColor(.clear)
              //  .sheet(isPresented: $safariViewPresented.animation()) {
                    SafariView(url: URL(string: "https://inside.integrity.ge.com/the-spirit-and-letter-booklet/EN/")!)
                //}
        } else {
            MainApp()
        }
    }

Comment: var body: some View {
        if safariViewPresented {SafariView(url: URL(string: "https://inside.integrity.ge.com/the-spirit-and-letter-booklet/EN/")!)}else {
            MainApp()
        }
    }

Comment: @Manojkumar please clarify what you need in the question more clearly next time. All three variants are possible, and I had to guess what do you need. See updated variant